# Get license files from all packages in virtual-environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I would like to collect the license documents for all packages installed in my virtual environment.

For this example, my virtual environment has two packages in it. The `pip freeze` is

```
numpy==1.18.3
tensorflow==2.1.0
```

For some of the packages (like `numpy`) I can use the tool [pip-licenses](https://github.com/raimon49/pip-licenses). However, this only works, if there is a `LICENCE.txt` file inside the pip package structure. For `numpy` this file is at `virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy-1.18.3.dist-info/LICENSE.txt`. But for `tensorflow`, there is no such file and I have to go to [GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/LICENSE) to retrieve the license by hand.

Why is the `LICENSE` file not included in the pip folder structure for `tensorflow` and is there a smarter way to collect the license of `tensorflow` (and other packages).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In [the neighbour question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61662812/7976758) I learned about [`pip-licenses`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint! There are some problems with `pip-licenses`. I have rewritten my question to take this problem into account.

Comment: The license file isn't included because the package is not put together properly (assuming that the license requires it be distributed with the package). I'm not sure there's a way to automatically retrieve these things if they're not in a standard location, sorry

Comment: Works for me. `pip-licenses` shows me "tensorflow              2.2.0        Apache 2.0" and `pip-licenses -l >licenses` saves to the file all paths and content of the licenses; for `tensorflow` the path is "site-packages/tensorflow-2.2.0.dist-info/LICENSE" inside my virtualenv.

Comment: You’re using Conda?

Comment: @phd: I think the difference is that you are using `tensorflow==2.2.0` while I am using `tensorflow==2.1.0`. I think @darthbith is right and it might not be possible if the file is not in a standard location...

Comment: @AMC yes I'm using conda